# How to update an object with a many to one relationship in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 4. I have two entities, Image and Anime, where each image can only be one anime. So in the Image entity I created an $anime variable and set it a "many-to-one" relationship to the Anime entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 */
class Image
{
    private $id;
    // and other properties

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Anime")      
     */
    private $anime;
}
```

In the Anime entity I have the id and name

```
Class Anime
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
}
```

When I migrate this, it successfully created both tables and added a foreign key "anime_id" under the "image" table. The problem I have is how do I update this "anime_id" through form submission?

This is my form, I only want to update the anime_id to my images.

ImageUpdateType.php

```
class ImageUpdateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder            
            ->add('anime_id', EntityType::class, [
                 'class' => Anime::class,
                 'choice_label' => 'name'
            ])
            ->add('update', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'update'));
    }
}
```

In the Symfony document, they just retrieve the entity object and do a setXXX() and that's it, but I don't have a $anime_id property in my Image entity. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In you form you have to use object's property not column:

```
class ImageUpdateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder            
            ->add('anime', EntityType::class, [
                 'class' => Anime::class,
                 'choice_label' => 'name'
            ])
            ->add('update', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'update'));
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to set it up in the controller